# Magento 2: EQP Error Possible useless method

Tags: magento2, error, overrides, methods, meqp2

I'm doing EQP of custom module then its shows error as below:

> **Possible useless method overriding detected**

**You can check this screenshot error is on line no. 20**

[image]

**Let me know if anyone has a solution.**

Comment: can you please add file so i can find solution ?

Answer (score 1):

**On your function definition add the below comment for avoiding this error:**

> // phpcs:disable Generic.CodeAnalysis.UselessOverridingMethod

**Like:**

```
// phpcs:disable Generic.CodeAnalysis.UselessOverridingMethod
.....
public function test(){
.....
}
```

*Example:* `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category:_getResource`

Comment: now working fine.but i need to solve without using any command.so can you help me more?

Comment: In cases, you have to used it or Your have to remove `__constuct()` function from your class. As per OPPS concept, if any  function  does not exist at your class and your class inherited from another  class, then that function need to call from parent class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you overriding the constructor, but you don't do any changes.

It is not needed.

Remove It

At least from the logic on the screenshot.